# SSL Generate Certificate Signing Request (CSR) for meteor app hosted on galaxy

Tags: ssl, meteor

I'm struggling to figure this one out. I've purchased a ssl certificate from godaddy and they are asking for a Certificate Signing Request. There is nothing on the Galaxy documentation that tells me how to do this. Am I missing something. Could someone please point me in the right direction.

Comment: If your going to put a negative next to my question can you at least explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to create a csr key, use the command below:

`openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout domain.key -out domain.csr`

Comment: It seem to kind of work but when I copied the domain.csr into the godaddy console it returns `Domain Name (based on CSR): None`

Comment: Sorry. I miss understood. I needed to replace domain.key with 'my-domain-name'